# Excel INDEX MATCH formula for multiple rows

Tags: excel, matrix, indexing, formula

I have hit a problem with my Excel spreadsheet and am hoping for some guidance. I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs, and in the "Matrix" tab I am trying to get cell `B2` to Index the data `'Matrix Patch' Row 1:1` if there is a "1" in any cell in `Rows 72:191`. The current formula I am using is:

```
=INDEX('Matrix Patch'!1:1,MATCH(1,'Matrix Patch'!72:191,0))
```

The answer I get is always N/A.

I can get it to work if I use:

```
=INDEX('Matrix Patch'!1:1,MATCH(1,'Matrix Patch'!72:72,0))
```

but that only works if there is a "1" in Row 72.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for formatting purposes can you leave a blank line in front of your formulas and start your formulas with 4 spaces in front.  I tried to edit it for you but it was too few changes to allow edits.

Comment: I cant tell what you are trying to by index in B2.  You talk about row 1:1  then you talk about 72:191.  can you please try explaining a bit more what you mean by index in b2?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH will only return the first value.  Is this what you want.  The first `1` in the lowest column in any of the rows mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Match only works for 1 dimensional arrays, so we need to use something different.

Also any answer will be an array formula and we should limit it to the dataset columns, no full row references

So we use the following:

```
=INDEX('Matrix Patch'!A1:INDEX('Matrix Patch'!1:1,MATCH("ZZZ",'Matrix Patch'!1:1)),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN('Matrix Patch'!A72:INDEX('Matrix Patch'!191:191,MATCH("ZZZ",'Matrix Patch'!1:1)))/('Matrix Patch'!A72:INDEX('Matrix Patch'!191:191,MATCH("ZZZ",'Matrix Patch'!1:1))),1))
```

This will return the first column that `1` is found in Row 72 to 91.

As stated before Array formulas should avoid full column or full row references in their calculations.  I put in `INDEX('Matrix Patch'!1:1,MATCH("ZZZ",'Matrix Patch'!1:1))` which finds the last column in row 1 that has text and set that as the last column in which to look.

If row 1:1 has number instead of text then we need to change all the `"ZZZ"` to `1E+99`.  Then it will find the last column with numbers in row 1.